# How to setup laravel project in Zend Studio?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, zend-studio

I've setup Laravel project in Zend Studio 11, but it can't see the dependencies classes as View , Route , etc .... . I've updated dependencies in composer but it still gives error , please help me

Comment: It can't see the classes as Input, View , etc..

Comment: http://bit.ly/Z9gngY

Answer (score 2):

Try using barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper composer package. It will generate dummy classes which will be scanned for code completition by ZendStudio. You can update autogenerated classes using Laravel artisan CLI tool.

From the author:

> This packages generates a file that your IDE can understand, so it can provide accurate autocompletion. Generation is done, based on the files in your project, so they are alway up-to-date. If you don't want to generate it, you can add a pre-generated file to the root folder of your laravel project.

more info on github project page: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper